# How to define a rectangle variable for rectangle input argument for CamShift?

Tags: c++, opencv

So I just started on c++ and OpenCV about two weeks ago and am not entirely sure what I'm doing. Basically, I'd like to give a rectangle a name so I can use it later if I need to and I'm not sure how to do that. 
 My current code:

```
Point p1= Point(0,0);
Point p2= Point(backproj.rows/4,backproj.cols/4);

rectangle trackWindow = rectangle(backproj, p1, p2, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0);
RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));
```

This throws an error of:

```
CamShift_Upload.cpp:108:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘trackWindow’
CamShift_Upload.cpp:108:79: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
CamShift_Upload.cpp:109:44: error: ‘trackWindow’ was not declared in this scope
```

So i'm obviously not declaring the rectangle variable the way I should, but I'm not sure of the correct way. Any help would be great.

Comment: Solution: Camshift takes 'Rect' objects not 'rectangle'. 'rectangle' is a drawing function, not a structure. Oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV `rectangle` function draws a rectangle to a Mat, it doesn't return anything. The function signature (see [the docs here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)) is

```
void rectangle(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0);
```

or equivalently,

```
void rectangle(Mat& img, Rect rec, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0);
```

Hence, the rectangle is drawn to your 1st parameter, the `Mat` named `backproj`. If you want a rectangle as a structure, you can use the OpenCV `Rect` structure. See [the docs for Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rect#Rect_). As it stands, you have a compile error because `rectangle` in your line `rectangle trackWindow = rectangle(backproj, p1, p2, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0);` isn't a valid type.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response,I just realized that myself. Guess I need to read the docs more carefully next time.

Comment: @user2387082 The docs can be a bit confusing, but they generally have most things you need to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

`rectangle` is the function call for drawing a rect, you probably wanted to create a `Rect` structure, like:

```
Rect trackWindow(0,0,backproj.rows/4,backproj.cols/4);
RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));
```